# Event Organiser: Event list includes regular Posts & custom fields?

Tags: events, plugin-event-organiser

I've recently tried setting up and using the plugin, [Event Organiser](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/). Unfortunately, when using the shortcode on my Calendar page it appears to have included the regular blog posts in the stream. They're not displayed the same way as my events list but if I remove that shortcode they also go away and I can't figure out how to make them go away while leaving the past event list intact. [See here](http://dev.zselter.com/KAF-wordpress/calendar/) for what I'm referring to.

The backend on the Page looks like this:

```
Upcoming Events
[eo_events showpastevents=false]

Complete List of Past Events
[eo_events event_end_before=today]
```

One other thing I would like to do is add meta data forms to the Event Details box on the back-end. I designed the original site ( http://www.kentuckyauthorforum.com ) several years ago, and am now trying to update it for design and convert it to Wordpress to make management easier. Part of that is being able to include event specific links to multimedia content (check the sidebar of one of the author pages for what I'm referring to), which I would like to be able to include in the Event Details and have appear in the sidebar of individual pages.

Anything you can suggest to help with either concern would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. if you can help, keep in mind I'm a novice when it comes to php coding.

Comment: Following the author's trail is what led me here actually, though upon further inspection he's not listed as one of the moderators...so I don't know. Anyway, I've done that as well, but I was trying all avenues — if this isn't the appropriate place then feel free to delete this post, as I don't want to clutter up the forums.

Comment: There are several plugin authors here who are using our site for support. [Stephen Harris](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris) is one of them, and your question should stay open. Being a moderator is something completely different. :) And welcome to our site.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong, Zack. Stephen Harris wants to offer support for his plugins here. Will remove the downvote. :) @toscho Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hi Zack - could you update the question to show exactly how are you using the shortcode? It should print the events as list inside `<ul>` tags - but I cannot see this mark-up on your site.